# User attributes values in db table - int or varchar?

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I have a dating site where each user has own profile with more than 20 attributes like age, gender, hobbies etc. For this I have table user_profile where all attributes are in 1 row.

For searching and match calculator, it would be probably better to have attributes values in int, better than having it in varchar. But now I am not sure how to print all attributes names if name is not also a value.

So I was thinking to create two tables:

```
user_profile
user_id | gendre | like_pets | drinks | body_type | eyes | hair_color | ...
1       | 1      | 3         | 2      | 4         |  5   | 5          | ...
2       | 2      | 4         | 2      | 3         |  3   | 5          | ...
```

```
user_attributes
id | attr_group | value_name | attr_value
1  | 1          | male      | 1
2  | 1          | famale    | 2
3  | 2          | Like pets | 1
4  | 2          | Have pets | 2
5  | 2          | Don't like pets | 3
6  | 3          | Blue      | 1
7  | 3          | Gray      | 2
8  | 3          | Green     | 3
9  | 3          | Brown     | 4
...
```

But that means I need to create 20 queries to print all value names for all attributes. For example to print eyes color I would need

```
SELECT * FROM user_attributes WHERE attr_group=3
```

then again the same for gender, and for each other attribute.

Is this a correct way?

Comment: Probably you didn't read my post carefully. I use columns, but in columns I use int values. So I need extra table to print value names for each column values. So "1" become "Doesn't smoke", "2" become "Smoke regulary" etc. I use int in columns for search purposes and for match calculator. It is faster than using varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is good to have a lookup table that has all the acceptable values.  (Yes, even if there are 20 of them.)  You can create a foreign key relation from the other table to the lookup table that'll tell you at time of row insert / update if the code is trying to link to a value that doesn't exist.  When you're ready to display the data, just join the tables, and harvest the name.

Comment: Yes, even if you need 20 joins.  Most of the time, you can get by with grabbing just their ids and joining to the names in the application's cached list of the lookup values.  If you're using Enums in the application, you can probably just cast the id to the proper enum type and use that as a semi-acceptable name.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly need all names for all attributes, just ask the database for exactly that:

```
SELECT * FROM user_attributes ORDER BY attr_group
```

Now do the grouping in your code after getting the results from the database. They'll be conveniently sorted, so it's easy to group up adjacent rows with the same `attr_group`.

To join this with the user table, I'd suggest you consider using another table to store the attributes, with columns `(user_id, attr_group, attr_value)`. Then you can join across this table and `user_attributes` to get all of your results.

Comment: Tnx, I will use this for user edit page where I need to display all attr names. But for user view page, I need to display only single value for each attribute. In this case it would be probably better to use 20x join? Or would be still faster without joins and making some extra php code?

Comment: @user1324762, why not just use a single join to get the currently-selected values for a particular user all at once?

Comment: This would be possible if attr values would be varchar, but as said for searching and match calculator purposes, I will use int. In this case it is impossible to use only 1 join.

Comment: I don't understand. What's wrong with something like `SELECT * FROM user_choices INNER JOIN user_attributes USING (attr_group, attr_value) WHERE user_id = ?`? It's hard to be more specific without seeing the rest of your schema though.

Comment: bdonlan Please check my schema now, I updated my post with both table schema. With one INNER JOIN you can not solve the problem, because one user_profile column has 20 different attributes and not only 1 attribute.

Comment: Ah, well, that's your problem - don't store them as separate columns if you want to be able to join them.